# Does React Redux not support pass-through functions from Parent -> Child?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I recently ran into a bug with my React Native & React Redux mobile app project.

In a nutshell, I have a parent component that then has a child component - where the child will call on a function that is passed in by the parent. Before this function is called, an initially empty array is added with +1 item (which both have access to) via `dispatch` by the child.

Let's call this function `onConfirm()`. Then, when `onConfirm()` (the prop function passed by the parent) is called, it then calls the parent's own local `onActionConfirmed()` method like so: `< ...props passed in.. onConfirm={() => onActionConfirmed()}... />`.

The contents of that exact array is printed out in the `onActionConfirmed` function - but instead of showing a populated array of length 1, it was empty in this function (a state behind). And to affirm my confusion, the `FlatList` that renders that data shows the item. How does that make sense.. at all..?

I have tried refactoring my code to ensure all components use the `useSelector` provided by React Redux, and ensured that *neither component used passed-in state data*. This did not resolve the issue. Every time I add in an item to the array (like in the example above), the array is one action (or state) behind when I print out its length / contents. For example, if I just added one item when it's a length of 0, it will print as length 0, or `[]` for empty array.